# narrow list on keyword input javascript

Tags: javascript

I have list of links:

```
<p>Use our search bar to narrow the list.</p>
<input id="sitemap-search" placeholder="Type to narrow list"><br>

<a class="sitemap" href="/49/brown-zircon-gemstones/s/1/round">ROUND BROWN ZIRCON GEMSTONES</a><br>
<a class="sitemap" href="/49/brown-zircon-gemstones/s/2/cushion">CUSHION BROWN ZIRCON GEMSTONES</a><br>
<a class="sitemap" href="/49/brown-zircon-gemstones/s/3/oval">OVAL BROWN ZIRCON GEMSTONES</a><br>
<a class="sitemap" href="/49/brown-zircon-gemstones/s/4/emerald-cut">EMERALD-CUT BROWN ZIRCON GEMSTONES</a><br>
```

and a bit of javascript:

```
$('#sitemap-search').on('keyup',function(){
  var keys = $(this).val();
  $.each($('.sitemap'),function(i,item){
    console.log($(item).text());
    if(!keys.toUpperCase().indexOf( $(item).text() )){
      $(item).hide();
    } else {
      $(item).show();
    }
  });
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to narrow down the list of links based on keyword input.

so if you type in cu, it should hide the other two links

Anyone want to help me out? Thanks!

Comment: If you type in cu, it'll show two - emerald-cut has those letters too.

Comment: cool, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Got it with:

```
$('#sitemap-search').on('keyup',function(){
  var keys = $(this).val();
  $.each($('.sitemap'),function(i,item){
    if($(item).text().search( keys.toUpperCase() ) > -1){
      $(item).show();
    } else {
      $(item).hide();
    }
  });
});
```